# Does Mifare 1k card support Java Card?

Tags: applet, javacard, mifare, globalplatform

I developed Java card applet on JCOP cards, and it's well loaded and worked fine.
Could I load the same applet on **Mifare** **1K** or **4K** card?
Because, I did not find any specification according to Java card or Global Platform support in the **MIFARE** documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

But there are Java cards with Mifare emulation available (by NXP and other vendors). Here MIFARE memory is accessible from your applet via special api ([JetZ](https://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jz20-mifare/com/ibm/jz/JZSystem.html), [Memory](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/index.html?javacardx/external/Memory.html)). Ask NXP for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Did you mean that there is no way to download applet into Mifare Classic1k?
I already have JCOP Cards from NXP, what does this Mifare emulation refer to?

Comment: @soth There is no way to run java card bytecode on MIFARE Classic. I updated the answer but you definitely need to contact NXP for the technical details.

Answer (score 2):

The applet in JCOP cards are only for Java Card platform that executes this applet. The MIFARE 1K or 4K can only store or use as secure storage following the DESFire API which had a fixed command set only related to secure storage but cannot do other stuff like run a custom applet. For custom applet, only a Java Card can do that. For example, a Java Card can emulate the DESFire API bcoz of a custom applet. But a MIFARE 1k/4k instruction set is fixed.